# What's the difference between HTML and SHTML now?

Tags: apache, ssi, shtml

I have learned that shtml is html with ssi, but I wonder I can set ssi even with html files in httpd.conf of apache:

```
AddType text/html .shtml .html
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml .html
```

if do so, the html files and shtmls are the same?

Thanks for your answering!

Comment: [Yes, if you activate SSI for the HTML extension it will be the same, in fact the extension doesn't matter, what matters is how you activated it and to what extension its assigned.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_include.html)

Answer (score 1):

SHTML is a file extension that lets the web server know the file should be processed as using Server Side Includes (SSI).

It looks like SHTML = Server Side include HTML (SSI), which is just a fancy way of saying the server can dynamically inject code at the reference point.

SHTML is server-side scripting.
HTML is the language used to define a Web page. It looks like text, with instructions on how the web browser should display the page

Use static HTML when you want to have static content. Use SHTML if you want to do simple things such as includes.

Comment: That does explain what it is but does not answer the question `I can set ssi even with html files in httpd.conf of apache, if do so, the html files and shtmls are the same?`.

Comment: Do you know if shtml and sshtml are same? What's the difference?